# cannot build silverlight library, what references do I need?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am converting a normal CLR library over to a silverlight library.

SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlClient aren't recognized.  What libraries do I reference?  I am working in Silverlight 3.0.

Comment: I'm not positive (still researching), but you may not be able to do that directly from Silverlight. Instead, you may have to set up a WebMethod (or something else) that your Silverlight app will call and grab the data. Checking....

Comment: this is an unwelcome surprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlClient are from system.data. System.Data is not part of the Silverlight.

For all database related activities, you should either use a webservice/wcf service/ria services/entity data framework for all crud operations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to directly access SqlServer from Silverlight. This makes sense since Silverlight is designed to create "web applications", implying that you'll need to use client-server methods to access the data. You could set up a WebMethod or WCF on a web server somewhere and point Silverlight at it to get the data.

References:
http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid-cs/
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/21012.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CntDbSlght.aspx